# Converting iOS application to mac application using Xamarin

Tags: ios, macos, monodevelop, xamarin

I am very new to Xamarin. I have built a simple iOS application (iPad actually) for testing. It is employee add. User puts in firsname,lastname,employee position int textfields and clicks save and it should save to DB. It works fine. Can i write/make a Mac application out of this iPad application using  the same code base? Please explain me. If you need more info, please ask.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse SOME of your code to create cross-platform apps.  If your App is well designed, with non-platform specific code (services, domain logic, data access, etc) separated from the UI and platform specific functions, then you should be able to reuse that code across platforms.  Things that are platform specific (particularly UI) will need to be customized for each platform.

Comment: Do you have an example of that..i.e. iOS->Mac..That would be greatly helpful for me.